# Java Generics, must a Class using Generics always be a Container of some type?

Tags: java, generics

It is pretty obvious that like an ArrayList is a container full of items of type "Generics".

How can a class make use of Generics except being a container? Any common usages?

Thanks!

Comment: The JDK is full of counter-examples.

Comment: @EJP Can you give me 10 of them? It should be easy since it is FULL of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple example is [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
```

That allows you to compare one person with another in a natural way.

Likewise there's [`Comparator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Person>
```

That allows you to compare any two people in a *specific* way. Neither of those interfaces is about a "container".

Then there are types like [`Future<V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), representing the promise of a value of type `V` at some point in the future (basically an asynchronous operation). Now you could think of this as a kind of container, but it's not a *collection*...

Fundamentally, generics are useful whenever you have an operation or type which is usefully parameterized by type (possibly with constraints) in order to maintain type safety, but can work with various different type arguments for that type parameter.